# Communicate Android with GSM modem

Tags: android, gsm

I'm trying to develop an Android application that connects to a GSM
modem. I like to know if it's possible to start the connection with
the modem (over GSM) and send text commands to the modem and listen
for its response.

Answer (score 0):

Normally mobile devices cannot accept incoming connections, these are blocked with firewalls in the mobile network.

The way around this is to put a server in the mobile network or on the internet wo which both, the android mobile and the GSM modem, connect to.

Comment: I need to comunicate directly to the modem. When the connection is made between modems I can make the GSM call send the commands and receive the data. I wanted to do this with a mobile phone with android.

Comment: So you intend to open not an IP connection but something else? You could look into CSD (circuit switched data).

Comment: @Bernd, you might be misreading the question. TAAT seems to ask how you can access the built-in GSM modem to initiate a data call.

Answer (score 0):

Communication with the GSM modem is done using AT commands within the Android OS. They are not able to be called directly by the Android Application without recompiling the OS with some modification.

Comment: "Communication with the GSM modem is done using AT commands within the Android OS." I don't think that's true. Could you provide a reference to the source?